# Did the last day of Moses start in Deuteronomy 9:1?

Tags: deuteronomy

Deuteronomy 9:1 New International Version

> Hear, Israel: You are **now** about to cross the Jordan to go in and dispossess nations greater and stronger than you, with large cities that have walls up to the sky.

English Standard Version

> “Hear, O Israel: you are to cross over the Jordan **today**, to go in to dispossess nations greater and mightier than you, cities great and fortified up to heaven

If this is Moses last day, that's a long day for him. His speech continues till the end of the book.

Comment: I agree that it means the whole rest of the book takes place in one day. I don't think this is so unbelievable, as you could easily read these speeches within a few hours.

Answer (score 2):

The Book of Deuteronomy consists of more than one speech of Moses:

- First Oration: Deut 1:6 – 4:43.  Historical background
- Second Oration:  Deut 4:44 – 26:19.  The Law of the Ten Commandments expanded
- Third Oration:  Deut 27:1 – 28:68.  Blessings and Curses of the law
- Fourth Oration:  Deut 29:1 – 30:20.  Renewal of the Covenant

The second oration is the longest and discusses the 10 commandment law in more detail.  It is divided into two sections: the general stipulations (Ch 5-11) and Specific stipulations (Ch 12-26).  The Specific stipulations can be broken down into sections expanding each of the 10 commandments:
1 & 2:    Deut 12:1 – 31 – Worship

3:    Deut 13:1 – 14:27 – name of God

4:    Deut 14:28 – 16:17 – Sabbath

5:    Deut 16:18 – 18:22 – Authority

6:    Deut 19:1 – 22:8 – Homicide/murder

7:    Deut 22:9 – 23:19 – Adultery

8:    Deut 23:20 – 24:7 – Theft

9:    Deut 24:8 – 25:4 – False Charges

10:   Deut 25:5 – 16 – Coveting

Now some simple facts:

- even in English - the book of Deuteronomy contains about 23000 words, much less in Hebrew.
- Speaking at a rate of about 150 words per minute would take about 2.5 hours to real aloud. (It is much less in Hebrew.)
- However, not all of Deuteronomy was spoken by Moses on that day (eg, he did not and could not have spoken Deut 34), making the exercise shorter, possibly only 2 hours, spread over four sessions of (say) about half an hour each.

Comment: This doesn't add up for me, as in Deuteronomy 27:2 he says "When you have crossed the Jordan..." meaning they haven't crossed yet. But in Deuteronomy 9:1, he clearly indicates they will cross the same day. So I think the only conclusion is that the four speeches (or at least speeches 2-4) occurred on the same day.

Comment: @Kidburla - I have added some simple information - all four speeches could have been delivered in one day without any trouble.

Comment: That's useful information and well-presented, but I still disagree with your statement earlier in the answer that "Moses' speech that day was not the entire book, but only Ch 4-26". Verse 9:1 clearly indicates that the later speeches also took place on the same day, as OP has highlighted.

Comment: @Kidburla - does it really matter - the entire book of Deuteronomy can be read in less than 2 hours in Hebrew (actually, about 1.5 hours).

Comment: Yes, it matters, because that's exactly what this question is asking. I'm not disagreeing with your statement that the entire book can be read in a short period of time. If anything, this only shows even more that the sentence I referred to is unlikely. Why not just remove that sentence from your answer - leaving just the implication (as I believe you intended in your edit yesterday) that all the speeches could indeed have been read in a single day?